# Replicate the functionality of iPhone Path App (click image and animates to Full Screen)?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

Does anyone know how I can replicate the iPhone Path App functionality when you click on an image from the news feed view.  Once clicked, the image grows (animated) to a full-screen view where you can pinch in and out to zoom.  A single tap reverses the animation and goes back to the news feed view.  It's a pretty neat implementation that I'd like to include in my app.

My initial guess is that the news feed contains a disabled UIScrollView and then the frame of the UIScrollView gets animated to the entire frame upon a tap.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is just have many UIButtons (with Custom image) as the thumbnails. And then assign IBAction to detect which image(button) is tapped. In this IBAction, animate the enlargement of the UIButton and at the end of animation, create programatically a UIScrollView and UIImageView. Insert the UIImageView into the UIScrollView. At this point you'd be able to pinch zoom and pan around the image. Then detect a touch and upon touch, remove and release the UISCrollView and UIImageView and animate back the UIButton to its original location and size.